# docker pull ending in unexpected EOF

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-repository

I have a quirky bug with my 'docker pull' function.

I create 2 images for a project on one local server, 2 repos on same docker service - for this description, we'll call those api and templates. I then log into remote servers to pull and deploy those images as containers.

The first one I do a pull like:

docker pull 10.9.8.7:5000/api:api-1

api-1 is the tag, and I can pull that one just fine.

For the templates pull,

docker pull 10.9.8.7:5000/templates:template-1

The pull starts and then goes into this hellish waiting/retry routine, finally ending in: unexpected EOF

I'm pulling from the same docker service - seems like I should have problems with both or neither.

I've seen this bug in my search and there's so many different suggestions, but looking for any input or suggestions on why it works for one and not the other.

Comment: Can it be a bad blob? You may need to delete the bad data and push the image again.